# Subset based on a criteria

Tags: macros, sas, subset

I want to subset my dataset (using sas) every time the count variable equals to 1. For example the following dataset would split into two datasets:

```
Over Ball      Bowling    Runs_scored Count 
39   1           Ali        1          1
39   2           Ali        1          2
39   3           Ali        2          3
39   4           Ali        1          4
39   5           Ali        1          5
39   6           Ali        1          6
36   1           Anderson   1          1
36   2           Anderson   1          2
36   3           Anderson   1          3
36   4           Anderson   0          4
36   6           Anderson   0          6
```

Note: Even though the final count in the above table, for each bowler, is divisible by 6 this is not the case in the actual (full) dataset.

I know that this task requires a macro but don't know where to begin.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: As I understand this query is related to "Cricket" and you want records of each "over" in a different dataset. Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the Test/Sample dataset

```
data test;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input Over : 8.
      Ball : 8.
      Bowling : $15.
      Runs_scored : 8.
      Count : 8.
;
datalines; 
39,1,Ali,1,1
39,2,Ali,1,2
39,3,Ali,2,3
39,4,Ali,1,4
39,5,Ali,1,5
39,6,Ali,1,6
36,1,Anderson,1,1
36,2,Anderson,1,2
36,3,Anderson,1,3
36,4,Anderson,0,4
36,6,Anderson,0,6
;
run;
```

Selecting the distinct overs(as I understand Cricket, each over would start with "1"`and that is what you are looking for)  and number of overs

```
proc sql noprint;
select distinct over into: overs separated by "," from test;
select count(distinct over) into :numOfOvers from test;
quit;
```

Creating a separate dataset for each over

```
%macro overnew();
 %do i=1 %to &numOfOvers.;

data over_%sysfunc(scan("&overs.",&i.,","));
set test;
where over=%sysfunc(scan("&overs.",&i.,","));
run;

%end;
%mend;

%overnew;
```

Comment: Thanks NEOmen! The code that you provided above has worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To separate dataset, use two dataset names in the data statement. And use output to direct the output;

```
data set1 set2;
    set input;
    if count = 1 then output set1;
    else output set2;
run;
```

So it means for each count = 1, add a separator and export a new dataset.

```
data test2;
    set test;
    retain n_count = 0;
    if count = 1 then n_count = n_count + 1;
run;
*calculate how many count = 1 in the dataset;
proc sql;
    select max(n_count) into :total trimmed
    from test2;
quit;

 %macro sep;
     %do i = 0 %to &total.;
        data sep_&i.;
            set test2;
            where n_count = &i.;
        run;
     %end;
  %mend;

  %sep;
```

Comment: What if it has 50 overs! Your solution is trivial to OP's example dataset.

Answer (score 0):

One more variation, that doesn't use macros, but uses call execute instead. First create a list of unique OVERS same as @neoman and then use call executes to generate the datasets.

```
data test;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input Over : 8.
      Ball : 8.
      Bowling : $15.
      Runs_scored : 8.
      Count : 8.
;
datalines; 
39,1,Ali,1,1
39,2,Ali,1,2
39,3,Ali,2,3
39,4,Ali,1,4
39,5,Ali,1,5
39,6,Ali,1,6
36,1,Anderson,1,1
36,2,Anderson,1,2
36,3,Anderson,1,3
36,4,Anderson,0,4
36,6,Anderson,0,6
;
run;

*Get all the unique overs in the list;
proc sql noprint;
create table test_unique as
select distinct over
from test
order by over;
run;

*create the call execute string to split the dataset;
data _null_;
set test_unique;

str1="data over"||put(over, z3. -l)||";";
str2=cats("set test (where=(over=",over,"));run;");
str3=cats(str1, str2);
call execute(str3);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing this where you won't have to loop through the dataset multiple times.  It also does not use macros and you don't need to know how many overs there are before running it.

```
data _null_;
    set have end=done;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        declare hash h_out(ordered:"ascending");
        h_out.defineKey("count");
        h_out.defineData("over", "ball", "bowling", "runs_scored", "count");
        h_out.defineDone();
    end;

    if h_out.add() ne 0 or done then do;
        ds_count + 1;
        h_out.output(dataset: cats('want', ds_count));
        h_out.clear();
        h_out.add();
    end;
run;
```

This works by creating a hash object that will store each over, and then when it reaches the end of an over or the end of the file the object is written out to a dataset.
The second "if" statement tries to add the row to the hash object.  Since we're using "count" as a key, this addition will fail if there already exists a duplicate value of "count" (i.e. count=1).  This will trigger the inside of the "if" statement which will increment the dataset count, output to the dataset, clear the hash, and add the current row that failed to add before.